# Retrieve password in text format from Hash_Secret format ie from salt in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, session-cookies

I'm writing a very simple login system for a Rails app. I'm using RESTful authentication. It's a fairly conventional setup, where I'm sending the email and password to authenticate the user.

Here, I used REMEMBER ME?, if same user again wanna login then by using cookie, user can re-login. Now thing is like, I want to print email and password in its respective text-box. Email is inserted into the textbox but I am facing a problem to show password in text-field.

At the time of login, such condition is used

```
@person.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(@password, @person.password_salt)
```

How can I get my password in text form?

Comment: I cn't believe this, if anyone found that this question is wrong or use-less. Then plz tell in comment box. Not by reducing the number. Its really a childish behavior of opposing anything. Sorry if I Hurt you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching the web, I found that `BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret` is one-way encryption of password. This means there is no way to reverse the process. So if you are trying to make password text from BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret, you cannot do it.

Comment: I don't use Rails, but this sounds correct. Bcrypt is a hashing function, which is not mathematically reversible. It is theoretically possible to use brute-force methods to search a large hash space to get the possible original passwords, but that is hard because there are collisions to think about (many values hash to the same value) and Bcrypt is very slow (by design).

Answer (score 3):

[irony]Why are you even hashing them if you want to display it in text form?[/irony]

But to be serious: hashing is one way operation, you can't revert it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Therefore you can't display user password (and btw - you shouldn't do it anyway, it's violation of the security principles).

When writing "remember me" feature, look at way devise is doing it: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable If you want that feature to be really safe, there is some amount of work required to code it.

Comment: Thanks Esse, But I used some different approach for re-login. Here I used authentication cookie and email in conditions to check whether user is valid or not.